# Cannot instantiate a scriptable object with location and rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a fairly straight forward third-person tower defense game, part of that is allowing the Player Character to move around and place towers. I have built the basic pieces, Player, Tower, Enemy etc, and now that I am writing the code to place the towers from the player I have encountered some issues.

Based on some tutorials from CodeMonkey I have been following, I have created my tower as a Scriptable object, and I am attempting to instantiate them at the mouse position in 3D. However, when I run the code, I encounter the following:

```
"ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate a ScriptableObject with a position and rotation
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <e97d84204f8d4aef92b538c5bab948f1>:0)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at <e97d84204f8d4aef92b538c5bab948f1>:0)
PlayerController.PlaceObject (TowerTypeSO placedObject) (at Assets/Scripts/Player Behaviours/PlayerController.cs:32)
PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player Behaviours/PlayerController.cs:25)
```

Here is the code I can think of that is relevant:
Player Controller for placement:

```
 // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            PlaceObject(activeTower);
        }
    }

    void PlaceObject(TowerTypeSO placedObject)
    {
        Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Mouse3D.GetMouseWorldPosition();
        Instantiate(placedObject, mouseWorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Mouse3D code for placement position:

```
public class Mouse3D : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Mouse3D Instance { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, float.MaxValue, layerMask))
        {
            transform.position = raycastHit.point;
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition() => Instance.GetMouseWorldPosition_Instance();

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition_Instance()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, 40f, layerMask))
        {
            return raycastHit.point;
        }
        else
        {
            return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

the Scriptable Object code itself is currently just a field for the prefab that has the basic tower prefab attached.

Any pointers as to how I can solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: scriptableobjects arent gameobjects... you dont instantiate them as it says

Comment: Use [ScriptableObject.CreateInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html) to create instances of scriptable objects.  In your case you want to instantiate the prefab that is referenced in the scriptable object eg. `Instantiate(placedObject.prefab, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scriptabel objects cannot be instantiated using the Instantiate function. That's because the Instantiate function specifically requires a UnityEngine.Object. In your particular case, you need to make sure that your TowerTypeSO has a reference to a GameObject(which is considered a UnityEngine.Object. Or more accurately inherits it). You can access this reference by using TowerTypeSO.prefab (Note: Replace "TowerTypeSO" with the actual variable name you're using).

If the TowerTypeSO doesn't currently have a prefab reference, you can add the following variable to it:

```
public GameObject prefab;
```

Feel free to modify the variable name and access level according to your preferences. In this case, using "public" as the access level is suitable since you need to access the variable from another script. Additionally, you might want to consider preventing the tower from being placed if the mouse position is undetected. Currently, the towers are placed at position zero and could potentially accumulate there.

Comment: `That's because the Instantiate function specifically requires a GameObject.` ... That bit is false! `Instantiate` requires an `UnityEngine.Object` and works on assets such as `Texture`, `Material` etc and as well `ScriptableObject` in which case it will create a runtime clone of the original ones. Of course your point is true nonetheless and OP's intention in this case is indeed to instantiate a certain `GameObject`, not to create a copy of the `placedObject` ;)

Comment: Thank you both! I appreciate the thorough explanations. I'm fairly new to both C# and Unity so it really helps.

Also, good shout on the mouse position being undetected, I stopped that from happening too.

Comment: You are welcome Jadon, and thanks for the note derHugo.